# Need help with categories system, nav and layered nav

Tags: magento-1.9, category, category-products, category-tree

I am setting up an online store for a company that sells vinyl records on magento.

I want to have an option on my main nav at the top that says 'genre' with a dropdown to every genre where each product will be assigned a genre. I created a category called genre with the genres as sub categories but I don't want genre to be its own category or have its own page.

[image: see image here]

If you look at the picture it says 'view all genre' but I want to get rid of that. Also if you notice on the layered nav on the left, when I search for an artist genre comes up at the side as a category but I want it instead to just come up with the different genres at the side (which are currently subcategories of 'genre'.

Anyone know how I would go about doing this properly? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To do so I reckon you create a new product attribute called Genre.

Please make sure you specify "Use in layered navigation" = Yes.

This way you will be able to filter your products by Genre without the need of subcategories.

Comment: Once this is done do you think I will also be able to have genre on the main nav at the top with a dropdown to all of the genres?

Comment: @OliTuck unfortunately not natively. You can probably create one programmatically but Magento does not handle such navigation item by default. It's your call to choose either subcategories or layered navigation attributes.

Comment: What if I had the genres as categories as well as attributes, would I be able to hide category from the layered nav and only have the attributes on there?

Comment: @OliTuck yes definitely that sounds feasible

Comment: Yeah, if I did that do you think there is still a way of making it so 'genre' doesn't have its own page but is still on the top with a dropdown to all of the subcategories. Because I don't want the option where it says 'view all genre'

Comment: The dropdown can be achieved with the layered navigation attribute so yes I think so

Comment: What I meant was. Can I make it so there is no existing page anywhere on the site for 'all categories' as I don't want the dropdown to also lead to 'all genre' as shown in the picture

Comment: if you only want to do this for one single category, I'm afraid the only way you can do it is by modifying directly the `page/html/topmenu/renderer.phtml` file